# Bezout's identity and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I tried to solve this problem:

> For a natural number $n$ and for a column matrix
> $$
> X=
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   x_1\\
>   x_2\\
>   \cdots\\
>   x_n
> \end{pmatrix}
> \in\mathcal{M}_{n,1}(\mathbb{Z}),
> $$
> let $\delta(X)$ be the greatest common divisor of numbers $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\geq2$ and let $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Prove that the following statements are equivalent:
>
> - $\lvert\det(A)\rvert=1$;
> - $\delta(AX)=\delta(X)$ for all $X\in\mathcal{M}_{n,1}(\mathbb{Z})$.

By Bezout's identity, the integers $x_1$, $x_2$, $\ldots$, $x_n$ not all zero, with greatest common divisor $\delta(X)$, exist integers $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\ldots$, $\lambda_n$ on
$$
  \lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\cdots+\lambda_nx_n=\delta(X).
  $$
Also, $\delta(X)$ is the least positive value of the linear form $\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n$ where $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\ldots$, $\alpha_n$ go on the integers.

If $AX=Y$, where $A=\bigl(a_{ij}\bigr)$, we have $y_i=a_{i1}x_1+a_{i2}x_2+\cdots+a_{in}x_n$, for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. $Y$ is the column matrix:
$$
Y=
\begin{pmatrix}
  y_1\\
  y_2\\
  \cdots\\
  y_n
\end{pmatrix}
\in\mathcal{M}_{n,1}(\mathbb{Z}),
$$
to guarantee that not all the integers $y_1$, $y_2$, $\ldots$, $y_n$ are zero, the matrix $A$ has to be regular, i.e., $\det(A)\neq0$.

With these considerations, we have to prove:

- $\lvert\det(A)\rvert=1\Longrightarrow\delta(AX)=\delta(X)$.

Because $AX=Y$, by Bezout's identity, we have:
$$
  \begin{aligned}
    \delta(Y) &= \mu_1y_1+\mu_2y_2+\cdots+\mu_ny_n\\
    &= \mu_1\bigl(a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\cdots+a_{1n}x_n\bigr)+\mu_2\bigl(a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\cdots+a_{2n}x_n\bigr)\\
    &\phantom{=}+\cdots+\mu_n\bigl(a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+\cdots+a_{nn}x_n\bigr)\\
    &= \bigl(\mu_1a_{11}+\mu_2a_{21}+\cdots+\mu_na_{n1}\bigr)x_1+\bigl(\mu_1a_{12}+\mu_2a_{22}+\cdots+\mu_na_{n2}\bigr)x_2\\
    &\phantom{=}+\cdots+\bigl(\mu_1a_{1n}+\mu_2a_{2n}+\cdots+\mu_na_{nn}\bigr)x_n\geq\delta(X)
  \end{aligned}
  $$
On the other side, if
$$
  AX=Y\longrightarrow X=A^{-1}Y
  $$
where
$$
  A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}(\operatorname{adj}A)^T=\bigl(b_{ij}\bigr)
  $$
because $\lvert\det(A)\rvert=1$, it guarantees that $A^{-1}\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Z})$.
For this, we have
$$
  \begin{aligned}
    \delta(X) &= \lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\cdots+\lambda_nx_n\\
    &= \lambda_1\bigl(b_{11}y_1+b_{12}y_2+\cdots+b_{1n}y_n\bigr)+\lambda_2\bigl(b_{21}y_1+b_{22}y_2+\cdots+b_{2n}y_n\bigr)\\
    &\phantom{=}+\cdots+\lambda_n\bigl(b_{n1}y_1+b_{n2}y_2+\cdots+b_{nn}y_n\bigr)\\
    &= \bigl(\lambda_1b_{11}+\lambda_2b_{21}+\cdots+\lambda_nb_{n1}\bigr)y_1+\bigl(\lambda_1b_{12}+\lambda_2b_{22}+\cdots+\lambda_nb_{n2}\bigr)y_2\\
    &\phantom{=}+\cdots+\bigl(\lambda_1b_{1n}+\lambda_2b_{2n}+\cdots+\lambda_nb_{nn}\bigr)y_n\geq\delta(Y)=\delta(AX)
  \end{aligned}
  $$
This proves that $\delta(AX)=\delta(X)$.

- $\delta(AX)=\delta(X)\Longrightarrow \lvert\det(A)\rvert=1$.

By hipotesis:
$$
  \mu_1y_1+\mu_2y_2+\cdots+\mu_ny_n=\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\cdots+\lambda_nx_n
  $$
then
\begin{multline*}
    \mu_1\bigl(a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\cdots+a_{1n}x_n\bigr)+\mu_2\bigl(a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\cdots+a_{2n}x_n\bigr)\\
    +\cdots+\mu_n\bigl(a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+\cdots+a_{nn}x_n\bigr)=\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2+\cdots+\lambda_nx_n
  \end{multline*}
identifying coefficients for each $x_i$, we the system:
$$
  \left.
  \begin{aligned}
    a_{11}\mu_1+a_{21}\mu_2+\cdots+a_{n1}\mu_n &= \lambda_1\\
    a_{12}\mu_1+a_{22}\mu_2+\cdots+a_{n2}\mu_n &= \lambda_2\\
    \cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots &\cdots\\
    a_{1n}\mu_1+a_{2n}\mu_2+\cdots+a_{nn}\mu_n &= \lambda_n
  \end{aligned}
  \right\rbrace
  $$
by that
$$
  \mu_i=\frac{
    \begin{vmatrix}
      a_{11} & \dots & \lambda_1 & \dots & a_{n1}\\
      a_{12} & \dots & \lambda_2 & \dots & a_{n2}\\
      \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
      a_{1n} & \dots & \lambda_n & \dots & a_{nn}
    \end{vmatrix}
  }{\det\bigl(A^T\bigr)}
  \text{ per a $i=1,2,\ldots,n$}
  $$
com $\mu_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ tenim $\lvert\det(A)\rvert=\bigl\vert\det\bigl(A^T\bigr)\bigr\vert=1$.

I wonder is this latter point (the identification of coeficients of the $x_i$) is correct cause of the not unicity of the $x_i$ coefficients in the Bezout's identity, I stuck about this. I appreciate any explanation about this.